# Delete records with nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I messed up my database and am trying to dig my way out. I've zeroed in on the issue but am insure how to delete the bad objects.

```
docs = @medical_relationships.map {|x| x.doctor }
```

gives me an array of doctors

```
@medical_relationships.map {|x| x.doctor.nil? }
```

gives me

```
[false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

So all those true values are users that I need to delete

I've tried    `@medical_relationships.map {|x| x.doctor.id }` but receive the original error of `NoMethodError: undefined method id' for nil:NilClass`

How can I delete these bad records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@medical_relationships` has some `nil` doctor because sometimes `x.doctor_id == nil`

if you want to choose valid items from array

```
@medical_relationships.select{|item| item.doctor.present?}
```

if you want to delete from database, do something like this

```
MedicalRelationship.where(doctor_id: nil).destroy_all
```

or update doctor_id value to the correct doctor

Answer (score 0):

you can use [delete_if](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)

```
docs = @medical_relationships.map {|x| x.doctor }.delete_if {|r| r == nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should not be done in this way.

I guess this happens when you delete the doctor record the reference is deleted in other tables. It is always better to use `dependent: destroy` 
option to delete the child records when parent records are deleted.